# Just can't find how to create a list from more than one line in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, xlrd

I'm outputting a column in excel using XLRD - with it outputting like below:

```
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    sheet.cell_value(row,0)


'user1'
'user2'
'user3'
```

However, I would like it in the form:

```
['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "list comprehension" mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
cell_values = [ sheet.cell_value(row,0) for row in range(sheet.nrows) ]
```

Result:

```
['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
```

Comment: There might be a better, more Pythonic way to do it, but I'm not familiar with XLRD